# How to disallow redirects to specific sites?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, safari

I would like disallow all redirects to specific sites (e.g. loomia.com).

How can I do this?

A browser-independent solution is preferable, of course, but if that's not available, I am looking for a solution for Firefox.

If it this is not possible at all in Firefox, then the next best would be a solution for the first of the following browsers for which it is at all possible: Chrome, Safari, IE, Opera.

Thanks!

PS: I know that in Firefox one can limit the number of all redirects, and one can set this number to 0 to disable redirects entirely, but this does not achieve what II want; for one, it makes normal browsing impossible, and is overkill anyway.

Comment: I think [NoRedirect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noredirect/) extension for FF will help you for this.

Comment: What are you trying to solve specifically?  Are you trying to write an application, or are you looking for something for yourself for when you're browsing around the internet?

Comment: @MaddHacker, I want to *selectively* prevent some redirects while I browser.

Comment: @avirk: Thanks!  (If you post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NoRedirect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noredirect/) extension for FF it will prevent the site to redirect on your PC. If you want to completely block a site on your PC then you don't have need to use plugin for different browsers just go to the following path..

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

You can use `Notepad` or `Notepad++` as any editor which is your favorite and run it as administrator. Now through the `File` menu select the `open` option and redirect to the above path and open the `hosts` file.

Now you have to just type

> 127.0.0.1 somthing.com
>   127.0.0.1 www.somthing.com

And this will block that site on your PC for any browser. To know how block site through localhost see my this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/410236/how-to-block-websites-in-localhost-file/410243#410243).

Comment: @kjo check my edited answer.